# How to clear the error messages while running the adf pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting error an while debugging the ADF pipeline such as

User configuration issue

ErrorCode=AdlsGen2OperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: 'filesystem' does not match expected pattern '^$a-z0-9[-a-z0-9]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$'.. Account: 'saworldemission'. FileSystem: 'True'. Path: 'True'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException,Message='filesystem' does not match expected pattern '^$a-z0-9[-a-z0-9]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

I need to rectify the error and to be success in loading the pipeline

Comment: can you provide your pipeline flow and dataset configurations and what are the activities that you are trying ?

Comment: i got resolved the issue thankyou for your concern

Answer (score 0):

Good to know that your issue got resolved. Based on the information of above error, I tried in my environment and got same error.

[image]

I got it when I have the file path in my dataset like below.

[image]

The below might be the reason for this error.

[image]

Here, you can see the container name does not support Capital letters in it and that's why the error in ADF states that it `'filesystem' does not match expected pattern`.

So, make sure your container name is correct as per your file path in storage account.